# Insert extra object into json

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, csv

After I converted the csv to json format and grouped by the specific data using `itertool.group`. I'm trying to insert a new object in the middle part to pass the existing data to the new object.

CSV file:

```
date,ref_num,description,debit,credit,coa_code,coa_name
2018-12-28,PV18/12/060,magicc,,916.60,310-1000,fineTaste
2018-12-28,PV18/12/060,youngClothes,916.60,,405-F005,magicc
```

Code

```
import csv
import json
from itertools import groupby

with open("ledgers.csv", "r") as csv_ledger:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_ledger)

    data = [dict(d) for d in r]
    groups = []

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r['ref_num'], r['date'])):
        groups.append({
            "date": k[1],
            "ref_num": k[0],
            "items": [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in ['ref_num', 
                     'date']} for d in list(g)]
        })

print(json.dumps(groups, indent = 4))
```

Result

```
[
    {
        "date": "2018-12-28",
        "ref_num": "PV18/12/060",
        "items": [
            {
                "description": "magicc",
                "debit": "",
                "credit": "916.60",
                "coa_code": "310-1000",
                "coa_name": "fineTaste"
            },
            {
                "description": "youngClothes",
                "debit": "916.60",
                "credit": "",
                "coa_code": "405-F005",
                "coa_name": "magicc"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the current result and I need to insert the `info` below the credit and this object will include the `coa_code` and `coa_name`. So I did try to add the info in the "items" but it does not work.

new code

```
with open("ledgers.csv", "r") as csv_ledger:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_ledger)

    data = [dict(d) for d in r]
    groups = []

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r['ref_num'], r['date'])):
        groups.append({
            "date": k[1],
            "ref_num": k[0],
            "items": [{k: v, 'info': {'coa_code': v}} for k, v in 
           d.items() if k not in ['ref_num', 'date'] for d in list(g)]
        })
```

Expected Result

```
[
    {
        "date": "2018-12-28",
        "ref_num": "PV18/12/060",
        "items": [
            {
                "description": "magicc",
                "debit": "",
                "credit": "916.60",
                "info": {
                         "coa_code": "310-1000",
                         "coa_name": "fineTaste"
              }
            },
            {
                "description": "youngClothes",
                "debit": "916.60",
                "credit": "",
                "info": {
                         "coa_code": "405-F005",
                         "coa_name": "magicc"
              }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import csv
import json
from itertools import groupby

with open("test.csv", "r") as csv_ledger:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_ledger)

    data = [dict(d) for d in r]
    groups = []

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r['ref_num'], r['date'])):
        items = []
        for i in g:
            info = {k: v for k, v in i.items() if k in ['coa_code','coa_name']}
            item = {k: v for k, v in i.items() if k not in ['ref_num',
                     'date', 'coa_code', 'coa_name']}
            item.update({'info':info})
            items.append(item)
        groups.append({
            "date": k[1],
            "ref_num": k[0],
            "items": items
        })

print(json.dumps(groups, indent = 4))
```

first I built `info` because it's much harder to extract later from `items`, then I made `item` which is each dictionary within `items` containing a single `info`. I then append 'items' with each 'item' to form my list of items within a group. Once the group is constructed I can append `groups` list with all the information. 
PS: I called my .csv `tets.csv` because I had that lying around, care to change the name.
Cheers!